# Terminate HTTPS on NLB for superset

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-eks, apache-superset

I have Superset setup on an AWS EKS cluster. I want to terminate HTTPS on the NLB layer, and send it to the superset via plain text.  This is how I set up the entire setup.

`GSLB Vip → NLB DNS Name → Nginx controller → http → ingress → service → pod`

When I curl the VIP/health, I get a response.

```
curl -ivk https://superset-xx.com/health
Connected to superset-xx.com port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: xxx.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ccc-bbb
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=dddd; OU=management:idms.group.5738053; O=asd Inc.; ST=California; C=US
*  start date: Oct 13 20:01:12 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 12 20:01:11 2023 GMT
*  issuer: CN=X Corporate Server CA 1; OU=Certification Authority; O=V Inc.; C=US
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /health HTTP/1.1
> Host: superset-xx.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.17.8
Server: nginx/1.17.8
< Date: Thu, 14 Oct 2021 00:25:43 GMT
Date: Thu, 14 Oct 2021 00:25:43 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 2
```

But when I hit the `login` or the `welcome` endpoint, it is stuck. It seems to be stuck at redirection. Every time I hit the URL, it seems to be recording this in the superset logs.

This is the controller yaml

```
Name:                     ingress-nginx
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
Annotations:              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:ssss
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: 443
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets:ss
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       1.2.3.4
LoadBalancer Ingress:     aaa.amazonaws.com
Port:                     http  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31840/TCP
Endpoints:                a.b.c.d:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 https  30330/TCP
Endpoints:                a.b.c.d:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     30599
Events:                   <none>
```

Any idea what could be wrong here? If you need any other configs, let me know.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In the routing section of your NLB, set protocol to TCP as opposed to TLS and that will terminate SSL for you

Comment: If the /health is working, doesn't it mean that the TLS termination is happening?

Comment: Did you set your protocol?

Comment: Yes, added that info the the main question as well